# Your Cloud Firestore database is denying client requests and will continue to do so until you update your security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Following my current security rule for Firestore for which it is denying my request:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if 
            request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 7);
          
    }
  }
```

Firestore works only when I set `write :if true`. I tried changing the date but it didn't work.

Following are the combination that I tried:

- 1. 

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if 
                request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 8);
              
        }
      }
    }
```

- 2. 

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if 
                request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 8);
              
        }
      }
    }
```

- 3. 

```
    rules_version = '2';
        service cloud.firestore {
          match /databases/{database}/documents {
            match /{document=**} {
              allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
                  
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the right rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 8, 31);
    }
  }
}
```

Which will work until the end of the current month.

Your rules don't work because `2022, 4, 8` represents the 8th of April 2022.

Comment: thanx for ur help , but it seems like some how 2nd case is working for me :


    `rules_version = '2';
        service cloud.firestore {
          match /databases/{database}/documents {
            match /{document=**} {
              allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
                  
            }
          }
        }
    }`

Comment: That will work only if your user is authenticated, which makes sense since the rule is not related to a specific date, but only to the auth state, right?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Hey Vishal. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: thanx for asking but i think i will be fine for some time

Comment: So did my answer help?